# Android achartengine the chart out of x-axis

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I use achartengine  to build chart in my Android project. But I got a problem. When I move the line.it will out of range, I want the chart when it bellow the  x-axis will disappear.

As the chart showed:  [image]